# How do I solve this "P/Invoke declarations should be portable"?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

This code:

```
[DllImport("shell32", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, out SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbFileInfo, uint flags);
```

Causes the following Code Analysis problem:

> **CA1901  P/Invoke declarations should be portable**
>
> As it is declared in your code, the return type of P/Invoke
>   'IconUtil.SHGetFileInfo(string, uint, out IconUtil.SHFILEINFO, uint,
>   uint)' will be 4 bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. This is not correct,
>   as the actual native declaration of this API indicates it should be 8
>   bytes wide on 64-bit platforms. Consult the MSDN Platform SDK
>   documentation for help determining what data type should be used
>   instead of 'int'.

What am I supposed to do? I tried "consulting MSDN", but I'm not really sure what the problem even means.

---

I also get this for the same line:

> **CA1060  Move P/Invokes to NativeMethods class**
>
> Because it is a P/Invoke method, 'IconUtil.SHGetFileInfo(string, uint,
>   out IconUtil.SHFILEINFO, uint, uint)' should be defined in a class
>   named NativeMethods, SafeNativeMethods, or UnsafeNativeMethods.

Comment: You declared `SHGetFileInfo` as returning `int`. Does `SHGetFileInfo` return `int`? According to MSDN, it does not. On x86, it's close enough. On x64, it isn't. That's what the first message is about.

Comment: When in doubt, check on Pinvoke.Net - they've usually got the signature right - [SHGetFileInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shgetfileinfo). Of course, if they do get the signature wrong, it's also good to contribute back, but I think they're correct in this case.

Comment: [CA1060](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182161.aspx) is pretty clear: you have placed the method declaration in a class named `IconUtil`, but it should be placed in a class named `NativeMethods`, `SafeNativeMethods`, or `UnsafeNativeMethods`. Check MSDN to find out which of the three you should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN page that the warning refers to is the documentation of the native function [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx). It gives the signature as:

```
DWORD_PTR SHGetFileInfo(
  __in     LPCTSTR pszPath,
  DWORD dwFileAttributes,
  __inout  SHFILEINFO *psfi,
  UINT cbFileInfo,
  UINT uFlags
);
```

So the first warning is referring to the fact that `DWORD_PTR` is a pointer sized unsigned integer. That means you should use `UIntPtr`.

The next thing that jumps out is that the `SHFILEINFO` struct is indicated as `__inout`. That means you need to pass it by `ref`.

So the p/invoke declaration should be:

```
[DllImport("shell32", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern UIntPtr SHGetFileInfo(
    string pszPath, 
    uint dwFileAttributes, 
    ref SHFILEINFO psfi, 
    uint cbFileInfo, 
    uint flags
);
```

The final warning is simple to resolve. Simply place your p/invoke declaration inside a class named `NativeMethods`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the first problem by changing return type of `int` to `IntPtr`.